# Do something after checking fields and before submiting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I need to execute certain code **after** all the inputs of a form are checked (I dont want check it manually) but **before** it sends the info to the backend.

I have to check if a custom checkbox is checked and if I click submit with this code:

```
$('my_form').on('click', function (e) {
    if (!$('custom_checkbox').is(':checked')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.termsError').fadeIn();
        return;
    }
});
```

It will only show the error feedback for the checkbox but not for the rest of the inputs.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show your other checks?

Comment: There is no other checks, I don't want to make any check manually, what I want is find a way to execute code after checking fields (part of the process when you click submit) and before sending all the data to the backed. I'm talking about the native process here.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the listener on the submit button and then programatically submit the form if it passes your validation conditions.

```js
$('button[type=submit]').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault() // stop the auto submission
  if (!$('#custom_checkbox').is(':checked')) {
    $('.termsError').fadeIn();
    return;
  } else {
    console.log('SUBMIT')
    // uncomment out the next line
    //$('#myForm').submit();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='myForm'>
  <div class='termsError' hidden>Please submit to the terms first</div>
  <label><input type='checkbox' id="custom_checkbox" name='custom_checkbox' /> I agree to the terms</label>
  <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```